# Kinect 360 not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kinect, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Kinetic in Ubuntu 16.04.
I have a kinect xbox 360 and the appropriate power supply.
The kinect works fine in windows 10.
In Ubuntu, it will not show up in lsusb. I can see the motor, but the rest of the components do not show. The best I can see is that it is being detected as a usb hub. But at each lsusb it changes IDs. Here is a sample from lsusb:

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04f9:0331 Brother Industries, Ltd
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0922:0020 Dymo-CoStar Corp. LabelWriter 450
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 15d9:0a33 Trust International B.V. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard LKS02
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 099: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
Bus 001 Device 098: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

running lsusb again gives:
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 056: ID 04f9:0331 Brother Industries, Ltd
Bus 001 Device 055: ID 0922:0020 Dymo-CoStar Corp. LabelWriter 450
Bus 001 Device 059: ID 15d9:0a33 Trust International B.V. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 057: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard LKS02
Bus 001 Device 054: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 052: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 050: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 101: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
Bus 001 Device 100: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

It looks like it is being detected as an NEC hub, but after many days of this I am not sure of anything.

Has this been encountered before? What can I do next?

Thanks,
Dave

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309609/kinect-360-not-working-in-ubuntu-16.04/) by [Dave Everett](https://answers.ros.org/users/427/dave-everett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2018-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks Orhan. I discovered the real problem. Non-microsoft 12v interfaces for taking the power to the kinect and splitting off the USB.

I ran some tests and it will only work if using a Microsoft USB interface adapter.
The Chinese one I had bought off Ebay will not work.

Dave

---

Originally posted by [Dave Everett](https://answers.ros.org/users/427/dave-everett/) with karma: 48 on 2019-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1